# При поиске только одного слова вся верстка летит

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток) Поиск работает нормально, но при при поиске только одного слова вся верстка летит, а также отключается sidebar и footer.... Что это может быть?

Comment: Может быть что угодно.. Нужно смотреть source и разбираться. Но 100% это проблема установленной темы..

Comment: Я думаю, стоит создать форму по CMS. Предложить эту идею ХэшКоду?

Comment: тоесть, нужно копаться в настройках самой темы?